# Angular: Pagination with Bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, pagination

I am trying to add pagination to my table by following this link:

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/table/examples
(under Pagination).

The problem is that I'm getting an error on map(product,i)..; this is the error:

- Property 'map' does not exist on type 'typeof Product'.
- Parameter 'product' implicitly has an 'any' type.
- Parameter 'i' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Will you kindly help me? Thank you all.

```js
import { Product } from '../product';
import { Observable, Subject } from "rxjs";
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private productservice: ProductService, private fb: FormBuilder, private modalService: NgbModal) {} 

  productsArray: any[] = [];
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  products: Product[] = [];
  product: Product = new Product();
  productlist: any;
  page = 1;
  pageSize = 4;
  collectionSize = Product.length;


  ngOnInit() {
  this.productservice.getProductList().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
      this.products = data;
      this.dtTrigger.next();
    })
    this.editProfileForm = this.fb.group({
      productcode: [''],
      name: ['']
     });

     this.refreshProduct();
  }

  refreshProduct() {
    this.products = Product
      .map((product: any, i: number) => ({id: i + 1, ...product}))
      .slice((this.page - 1) * this.pageSize, (this.page - 1) * this.pageSize + this.pageSize);
  }
  .
  .
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably meant to do the below:

```
  ngOnInit() {
      this.productservice.getProductList().subscribe(data => {
          this.products = data;
          this.dtTrigger.next();
          this.refreshProduct();
      })
      this.editProfileForm = this.fb.group({
          productcode: [''],
          name: ['']
      });
  }

  refreshProduct() {
      this.productsArray = this.products
          .map((product: any, i: number) => ({ id: i + 1, ...product }))
          .slice((this.page - 1) * this.pageSize, (this.page - 1) * this.pageSize + this.pageSize);
  }
```